# How to specify date format for date data type in oracle apex form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I want to specify a specific format for a date column in Oracle Apex 19.2 form to limit the user to input the data in a specific format. For example, I want this query for a form to be valid:

```
Select phone_no, call_date, to_char(call_time, 'HH12:MI:SS AM') 
FROM called_no;
```

Note: `call_date` and `call_time` has the same data type which is `date`. I only have the problem with `call_time` column.

Answer (score 1):

Well, format mask for `call_time` item would be as you said: `hh12:mi:ss am`.

If you didn't already do that, do it. If you did, what problems did you have?

---

However, from my point of view, you're doing it wrong - you should use only one column: `call_date` whose datatype is `date` and use it in Apex "as is". It (the item) would accept full date AND time in desired format, e.g. `dd.mm.yyyy hh12:mi:ss am`.

Because, if you use two columns/items, you'll hit a problem that `call_time` column's **date** component will be *wrong*. Have a look:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh12:mi:ss am';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate,
  2         to_date('05:33:12', 'hh12:mi:ss pm') right_now
  3  from dual;

SYSDATE                RIGHT_NOW
---------------------- ----------------------
22.12.2021 05:34:19 PM 01.12.2021 05:33:12 AM
-----                  -----
today                  see this? Date component is truncated to 1st of current month
```

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: If I use only the call_date column with date data type I can not insert the date and time at the same time in one column because apex only allows me the date to insert it not the time section when I set the type of that field as date picker.

Comment: I don't have Apex 19 any more, but - in more recent versions, Apex lets you set **show time** property (1 on screenshot) which results in time component displayed in date picker item (2 on screenshot); when clicked, it lest you *select* time. **However**: even if date picker does NOT offer time, nobody prevents you to enter date and time **manually**.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't seen that feature of apex before. so I have to update my apex which will realy solve my problem.